# How to manage backstack in Acitivity Stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

If I have `6` activities say `Activity1 ,Activity2, Activity3, Activity4, Activity5, Activity6` the flow is `Activity1-> Activity2-> Activity3-> Activity4-> Activity5-> Activity6`. I want to go to `Activity3` from `Activity6` only if I am on `Activity6`. if I am at `Activity4` or `Activity5` then normal back stack will work. I don't want to clear the activity from top unless I'm at 6th. So please read what I am asking before marking it as duplicate

Comment: check  https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation?hl=en#0

Comment: this is not what I was asking I don't want to clear when I go to 5 activity I will clear the last two top only I am at the 6th activity. I have already done this but not my solution @JaiprakashSoni

Comment: Do you mean you want this to happen when the user uses the system back function? If so, you should clarify that in the question.